# node request pipe hanging after a few hours

Tags: node.js

I have an endpoint in a node app which is used to download images

```js
var images = {
  'car': 'http://someUrlToImage.jpg',
  'boat': 'http://someUrlToImage.jpg',
  'train': 'http://someUrlToImage.jpg'  
}

app.get('/api/download/:id', function(req, res){
  
    var id = req.params.id;

    res.setHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=image.jpg");
    request.get(images[id]).pipe(res);

});
```

Now this code works fine, but after a few hours of the app running, the endpoint just hangs.

I am monitoring the memory usage of the app, which remains consistent, and any other endpoints which just return some JSON respond as normal so it is not as if the event loop is somehow being blocked. Is there a gotcha of some kind that I am missing when using the request module to pipe a response? Or is there a better solution to achieve this?

I am also using the Express module.

Comment: Try configuring a timeout for `request.get()`.

Answer (score 2):

You should add an error listener on your request because errors are not passed in pipes. That way, if your request has an error, it will close the connection and you'll get the reason.

```
request
.get(...)
.on('error', function(err) {
  console.log(err);
  res.end();
})
.pipe(res)
```

Comment: Any errors in `request.get()` will be thrown regardless of the presence of an `error` handler (although having an explicit error handler isn't a bad thing here).

Comment: Could you elaborate on why this error would be thrown regardless?